# Flowchart for function overloding

Tags: algorithm, flowchart

How we can draw flowchart and algorithm for function overloading

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int area(int);
int area(int,int);
float area(float);
float area(float,float);
```

*Main function here*

```
int main()
{
    int s,l,b;
    float r,bs,ht;
    cout<<"Enter side of a 
    square:";
    cin>>s;
    cout<<"Enter length and 
    breadth of rectangle:";
    cin>>l>>b;
    cout<<"Enter radius of 
    circle:";
    cin>>r;
    cout<<"Enter base and height of triangle:";
    cin>>bs>>ht;
    cout<<"Area of square is"<<area(s);
    cout<<"\nArea of rectangle is "<<area(l,b);
    cout<<"\nArea of circle is "<<area(r);
    cout<<"\nArea of triangle is "<<area(bs,ht);
}
```

*For square*

```
int area(int s)
{
    return(s*s);
}
```

*For rectangle*

```
int area(int l,int b)
{
    return(l*b);
}
```

*For circle*

```
float area(float r)
{
    return(3.14*r*r);
}
```

*For trianle*
    float area(float bs,float 
     ht)
    {
       return((bs*ht)/2);
    }
*It is possible to draw flowchart and algorithm for this program*

Comment: The question is unclear, you want to generate flow charts from code? or do you want to know how to create a flow chart?